# zprofile missing in OS X Big Sur and "read only filesystem" rejects creation of zprofile

Tags: zsh, macos-big-sur

Experiencing this issue on a brand new M1 MacBook Air. Attempted to follow [this guide](https://michael.codes/posts/nodejs_apple_silicon/) to set up `nvm` and Node. It worked at first but on subsequent sessions I started to get

`zsh: command not found: node`

`zsh: command not found: npm`

Et cetera - I realized I am running `zsh` and for some reason, I do not have a `.zprofile`, only a `.bash_profile`. `tail ~/.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I cannot create a `.zprofile` file because I get `touch: /.zprofile: Read-only file system`.

I could try and force it with `sudo`, but given that I've messed up the rudimentary setup of this system, I am not inclined to further foobar the setup without a little assistance.

Comment: You won't be allowed to create a file inside `/` for good reason. Why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
touch /.zprofile
```

To

```
touch ~/.zprofile
```

There is a huge difference!

Comment: (And if you don't know what that huge difference is, I would say don't give _any_ commands in the Terminal, as you can do massive damage if you don't know what you're saying.)

Comment: Thanks. Hence why I had the intuition not to force it with `sudo`. My `node` and `nvm` commands are still not working, but I am thinking that is because the guide I followed appeared to be meant specifically for bash.. Not sure how to fix that at the moment.

Edit: I figured it out - I just had to add the same lines to my `.zprofile` file. Thanks!

Comment: I personally think saying "don't give any commands in the Terminal" is terrible advice. I would say, be aware that you might bork something, so don't do it on a prod server or anything like that, but you have to be willing to mess stuff up to learn. Experiment, break stuff, google it to learn how to fix it. That's how you learn, or at least how I do.

Comment: @Travis I didn't say "don't give any commands in the Terminal" plain and simple. I said it as part of a larger context starting with "if".

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I meant that even in that larger context, don't be afraid to experiment and break something.

Comment: @Travis someone who doesn't know what `rm -rf` can do _should_ be afraid to experiment and break something. You make it sound as if nothing can go wrong. It can. It can go very, very wrong.